# Xcode organizer app submission error

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect, xcode-organizer

I am getting this error when I try to distrubute an app via xcode organizer.
I am using latest public version of Xcode and latest SDK, so it does not make any sense.
Anybody suggest a solution?

Thanks in advance.

[image: Screenshot of error]

Comment: Have u checked your Xcode Version and Build?

The last Xcode version should be 5.1.1 (5B1008)

Comment: @webmastx yes of course. I already have 4-5 apps on the appstore, so I know what I am doing... It seems that itunes connect was under some maintanaince or something, i tried again and it worked. Thanks for your help :)